# Selfclosing confirm box

Tags: javascript, confirm

I am building a web app and I am trying to do a function where there is a popup confirm box that shows after the user has been inactive for 10 minutes. When the popup opens the user can choose to continue being logged in or not. I need this box to close down after 1 minute if they have not answered the popup. How can I do this. Everything else works fine.

**This is my code:**

```
function checkTime () {

 setTimeout (function () {

   var dialog = confirm ("Do you want to continue being logged in?");

   if (dialog == true) {

     checkTime ();

   } else {

     window.location = 'LOGOUT URL';    

   }

  }, 10000);

};
```

Comment: try self-developed confirm box

Comment: I rather use the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with the native confirm() as it stops JavaScript run on that page until the user has clicked on it.

So, You have to create a plugin for confirm-box or try someone else.
And they often look better, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't make the confirm close itself - as a thought path my bank has the same sort of thing on their on-line banking system - quite simply if you walk away and come back, it you've been longer than 10 minutes it doesn't matter what you chose it apologizes and logs you out anyway

the dialog requires human interaction it can not be overridden for security reasons. in order to do what you are trying to you would need to use a modal solution (this can be achieved with a small amount of js and some css if you don't want to use a third party solution)

I know it's not the answer you were looking for I'm sorry but hopefully it gives you some ideas for options